# CTRL + A, ENTER, keystrokes for music batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Every time I turn on my PC I open a specific folder (Music), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to choose all the songs, and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to play them with Windows Media Player.

I want to create a batch file (or cmd doesn't matter) that navigates to the specific folder, then executes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>enter</kbd>.

I've come across commands like "Start" but it doesn't really work with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. I also found some commands like "ECHO x.SendKeys "{ENTER}"" but still not much luck with it either.

Comment: Windows `cmd` and so batch files are not capable of sending key-strokes, so you need to use something else; perhaps you are interested in [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com) or [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com)...

Comment: Why not replace the `Ctrl+A` by simply playing a playlist for that folder? I'd guess WMP accepts a playlist (or maybe even a folder) as a command line argument.

Comment: From [WMP command line parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562624(v=vs.85).aspx): `wmplayer /Playlist PlaylistName`  *Open the Player and play the specified playlist.*

Comment: First of all thank you both for the reply.
My main concern about the playlist thing was that being super lazy as i am i would have to add the new songs not only to the folder but to the playlist too. The folder gets a new song about every week so... But if the playlist can get the newest entries automatically im in for the idea

Comment: The Answer below is fast and works. Thanks a lot for your time masters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script lists all files in the directory "...\music" (replace this with the full path of your music folder) and stores them in a M3U playlist file. Then it starts Windows Media Player provided with the path to the playlist.

```
setlocal
set "musicDir=...\music"
set "list=playlist.m3u"

dir /b "%musicDir%" > "%musicDir%\%list%"
start wmplayer "%musicDir%\%list%"
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply.
I have successfully replaced the path directory, but the items do not seem to be stored in the playlist. The WMP is indeed launching but with nothing to play

Comment: Never mind I am just an idiot and accidentally deleted a ". Thank you very much